# How to pass to NSMutableData.appendBytes an array index position different from zero

Tags: swift, nsmutabledata

I've an `[UInt8]` array containing ASCII codes and I want to create a String from it passing from a `NSMutableData`

I use the method `appendBytes` and pass to it the swift array address and everything works fine

The problem is when I need to pass a different from zero index, the expression `&arr[5]` is obviously wrong

The example below shows how to create the string starting from zero and taking 5 characters (the string "hello").

How do I must modify the code to start from position 6 and get the string "world"?

```
    var arr = [UInt8](count:100, repeatedValue:0)
    arr[0] = 104 // h
    arr[1] = 101 // e
    arr[2] = 108 // l
    arr[3] = 108 // l
    arr[4] = 111 // o
    arr[5] = 32 // space
    arr[6] = 119 // w
    arr[7] = 111 // o
    arr[8] = 114 // r
    arr[9] = 108 // l
    arr[10] = 100 // d
    var data = NSMutableData()
    data.appendBytes(&arr, length: 5)
    let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
    println("string from index zero = \(str)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap byte array into `NSData` and access required bytes using `subdataWithRange(...)`, here is the code:

```
let readOnlyData = NSData(bytesNoCopy: &arr, length: arr.count) // notice bytesNoCopy, working with the same bytes
let subRangeData = readOnlyData.subdataWithRange(NSMakeRange(6, 5))
let str = NSString(data: subRangeData, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
```

Comment: This helps very much, maybe I can work directy with `NSData` and remove the `arr` just to mimimize the objects to allocate. It's really frustrating converting a simple pointer operation in many allocations...

Comment: NSData is a wrapper designed for efficient work with arrays(code wise). I suggest you to go with it. In addition NSData very well integrated with NSString and other classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subarray and pass reference to it:

```
var subA = Array(arr[6...10])
data.appendBytes(&subA, length:subA.count)
```

Comment: So addressing a simple pointer becomes a very inefficient code, my real code is inside a loop so creating dozen of subarrays is overkilling

Comment: Swift arrays are copied lazily -- I haven't checked, but constructing an `Array` from a `Slice` of another should get you the same bytes. (You could probably test this by writing an ObjC test case and passing it various Swift subarrays, then looking at the pointers your ObjC code receives.)

Comment: @rickster `Slice` is not an `Array`, I mean `appendBytes(...)` does not accept slice pointer, that is why I had to pass it into `Array(...)` constructor. With `var` in front of variable it should definitely eat additional memory due to copy of items. I have posted another answer that solves the problem using `NSData`, hope it can help.